# Different ways to read string with white spaces as input?

Tags: java, string

I have a string like

> 01 01 01 02 01 01  20 00 40 0b 00 01 ef cc 45 4e  47 00 1a 02

How can I read this as input? I know declaring

```
String s = "01 01 01 02 01 01  20 00 40 0b 00 01 ef cc 45 4e  47 00 1a 02"
```

will obviously throw me error, so what are different possible ways I can read this input (passed as arguments) using Java?

Comment: "*read this as input*" What do you mean? How are you reading it?

Comment: Var Args, Scanner or Reading from file

Comment: Why do you say declaring the string will "obviously throw \[you\] error"?

Comment: because it has whitespaces, i think i got a number format exception!

Comment: Your string declaration will not throw error. You have one string

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to turn that string into an array of bytes, where the things between the whitespace are the hexadecimal representations of numbers?

Comment: Yes thats hexadecimal representation, i thought it was obvious to know its hexadecimal :)

Comment: I mean is the string representing a single number or an array of bytes?

Comment: What is your requirement exactly? Given the string, do you want to extract each number individually, turn it into an array of bytes? What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to read this in as hexadecimal data, not as a string.

Start by removing the whitespace in the string, so it should look like "0101010201012000400b0001efcc454e47001a02"

Then, create a BigInteger to hold it like so:

```
BigInteger hex = new BigInteger(s, 16);
```

Now you should have the hexadecimal value stored in the variable hex.

Comment: That particular string is too big for a long.  Change your answer to use a `BigInteger` for an upvote. :)

Comment: This should be my answer! yes BigInteger would give u another vote ;)

Comment: Oh, you're right, whoops! I'll change it over in a minute.

Comment: +1 All good now.  Yes the BigInteger constructor is preferred.

Comment: I never knew until I saw your answer and looked it up then that you could pass a radix value to BigInteger's constructor for easy conversion. You learn something new every day on this site :D

Answer (score 2):

If you passed them as variable arguments then you can get it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length() > 0) {
        String myInput = args[0]; //Here is where you get them...
        //Process myInput
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your mystery number

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new BigInteger("01 01 01 02 01 01 20 00 40 0b 00 01 ef cc 45 4e 47 00 1a 02".replaceAll("\\s+", ""), 16));
  }
}
```

It's

```
5731379310208105099069359549013101637718252034
```

See the live demo at http://ideone.com/uGh17

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "01 01 01 02 01 01 20 00 40 0b 00 01 ef cc 45 4e 47 00 1a 02";
```

should work...

Comment: nope I am pretty sure it will throw Exception!

Comment: No, that line of code will compile and won't throw an exception.

Comment: Try it out @SuperMan.  Or tell us more about what you are doing.